# Dynamic source with Conduit

Tags: haskell, conduit

I have a list that is constantly growing in parallel thread, for example inside `IORef [a]` or `MVar [a]`. I want to sink it also in parallel until the thread exits. How should I implement this? It may look something like this:

```
main = do
  list <- newIORef []
  forkIO $ grow list
  ...
  result <- ... $$ sinkHash
  return result
```

Or maybe there is a better way without growing a list and sink every chunk that were produced inside the thread directly one after another?

Comment: Perhaps look into `Chan`s?

Comment: Or at least explain why you are mutating the list vs just giving the sink the latest elements

Comment: @jozefg Thanks. I'm gonna look into `Data.Conduit.TMChan` and `Data.Conduit.TQueue` now.

Comment: @jozefg as your comment answered the question, perhaps you should post it as an answer?